# Cómo debo modificar el condicional para evitar error de compilación argumento no opcional

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo una macro que limpia la pantalla y elimina una hoja especifica si esta ha sido creada, para esto cree una función que valida si esta fue creada:

```vb
 Function BuscarHoja(TablaDinamica As String) As Boolean For i = 1 To
    Worksheets.Count
       If Worksheets(i).Name = TablaDinamica Then
            BuscarHoja = True
    Exit Function
       End If
    Next
    BuscarHoja = False 
End Function
```

Luego en la macro en donde se limpia la pantalla me tira error de compilación diciendo que el argumento no es opcional y me subraya todo este sub:

```vb
Sub Limpiar_Pantalla()

'Macro para Limpiar_Pantalla

'Selección de las 4 columnas en donde se trae la información y se elimina el contenido de estas
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

'Se elimina la hoja TablaDinamica si se ha generado

If (BuscarHoja = True) Then
    Sheets("TablaDinamica").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Range("A1").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: En la línea de la instrucción `Function` no deben incluirse otras instrucciones como `For` (véase https://msdn.microsoft.com/ES-ES/library/office/gg264233.aspx). Pareciera un error de tipográfico o de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function EliminarSheet(nombreSheet As String) As Boolean

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = nombreSheet Then
            Sheets(nombreSheet).Delete
            EliminarSheet = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    EliminarSheet = False

End Function
```

Te dejo mas referencia
http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-worksheet/

Comment: En el link hay buena información, pero no resuelve el error ya que si elimina la hoja siempre y cuando esta este creada pero si no esta tira el error de compilación, para esto valido que si este con el function.

Comment: @andrezrestrepo Ya edite la respuesta, fíjate si te sirve

Comment: Perfecto ya funciona la macros, ademas tome la linea de código del enlace que evita que muestre un cuadro de dialogo para eliminar la hoja, no la conocía. Gracias

Comment: De [answer]: `Ofrece contexto para los enlaces

Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudara a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porque decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar l aparte mas relevante del enlace por si la pagina web desaparece or es cambiada en un futuro.`